# How can I specify a resource root for SCSS includes in my Webpack sass-loader config?

Tags: sass, webpack, libsass

Say I have something like:

```
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
}
```

in my webpack config and I have a `app/` sub folder with all my SCSS and JS files in.

Currently to import an SCSS partial I have to `@import 'app/whatever/my_partial';` for it to be recognised.

How can I set the loader to treat `app/` as a resource root for these files so I can just say `@import 'whatever/my_partial'` ?

This is with Webpack 2.x btw.

Any help from you clever people much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `app/` to the `includePaths` option in the `sass-loader`. Your `.scss` rules has to be changed to:

```
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  use: [
    'style-loader',
    'css-loader',
    {
      loader: 'sass-loader',
      options: {
        includePaths: [path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'app')]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for that! Had to alter this slightly so the path line read `includePaths: [path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'app')]` (just errored out otherwise) , but after that it's working great. (updated your answer - hope you don't mind)