# Set scss path using alias in angular-cli library project

Tags: angular, typescript, sass

I'm creating a library project using angular-cli. By following the instructions from the [angular docs](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-create-library), I end up having one `./root/src/app` folder where I can put a test application demonstrating the capabilities of my library, and one `./root/projects/library-name` folder containing the functionality of my library.

Now, if I in my `./root/src/app` want to import modules/components/classes etc, angular-cli allready has set up my tsconfig.json for me, with a key/value paths config.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "my-library/*": [
        "dist/my-library/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This will for all purposes regarding our `./root/src/app` mimic our library being installed as a node_module.

So even if the library is built to `./root/dist/library-name`, the following works great in my test app:

```
import { MyLibraryModule } from 'library-name';
```

**Problem**

SCSS does not conform to the same rules as described under tsconfig.json. 
If my library contains some scss I wish to make available for consumers of my lib, I can do that. Everyone installing my library can reach my scss through

```
@import '~library-name/scss';
```

but my test app cannot.

**Question**

How can I configure my scss preprocessor config in `angular.json` in such a way that it mimics what angular-cli has done with my `tsconfig.json`, but for scss? In other words; how can I configure angular-cli to set up a directory alias for my library build output?

**EDIT** Just to clarify, my scss is reachable once the library is published. No problem when it is consumed by other applications. My problem is reaching the published scss inside my `./root/src/app` test application.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my own project. I wanted to have some scss files exported along side my library, something like angular material's themes folder. I found using `scss-bundle` library a good solution cause apparently there are no ways to do so using angular cli.

Using `scss-bundle` is pretty simple. You need a config file, something like:

```
{
    "entry": "src/lib/themes/_core.scss",
    "dest": "dist/themes/_theme.scss"
}
```

and run this command every time you build your lib: `scss-bundle -c ./scss-bundle.config.json`

and here is the [github repo](https://github.com/SimplrJS/scss-bundle) in case you have different needs

**UPDATE: Changing sass loader config so that you can import scss files easier inside application project**

If you want to import scss partials as you do from node_modules you need to change webpack and sass-loader configurations. WEbpack configuration is hidden by default in angular cli depending on your cli version you have to ways of changing it.

**1.x** You need to use `ng eject` to "eject" webpack config file. [Official docs](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/1-x-eject) for that

**6.x** In cli v6 `ng eject` is disabled temporarily, BUT there is still a way to get around that, you can find a well written guide to it [here](https://codeburst.io/customizing-angular-cli-6-build-an-alternative-to-ng-eject-a48304cd3b21)

and after all these you need to configure `sass-loader` to consider your lib project as a root path that you can find the answer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43544601/how-can-i-specify-a-resource-root-for-scss-includes-in-my-webpack-sass-loader-co)

Comment: The problem isn't in making scss available from `./library/projects/my-library`. The problem is `@import '~my-library/scss'` from my code in `./library/src/app/` (my test application)

Comment: But good to know if I want to bundle my scss, and not offer it as single files. Thank you for that.

Comment: @ØysteinAmundsen Oh I see, sorry for misunderstanding, that one is kind of harder now. I will update with what I know and found on internet hope it helps

Comment: Wow! The solution you propose in your update seems rather complex. Isn't there any easier way to do this?

Comment: @ØysteinAmundsen not as far as I know

Comment: In modern days you don't have to eject in order to customize Angular build process and Webpack config. For example, you can use this to add extra webpack configurations: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack